# Why the result of IsDigit is not as intended

Tags: c#

In the below code if I enter numbers then it flashes error message instead it should flash in case of alphabets. I want to allow only numbers.

Also if I enter number and then any alphabet for e.g. 33er then the error msg is displayed and unless and untill I do not remove whole text the msg flashes, I have remove whole text and then I have enter numbers.

```
if (e.Handled != char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
   errorProvider1.SetError(label1, "Allow Only Numeric Values !");
   label1.Text = "Allow Only Numeric Values !";
}
else
{
   errorProvider1.SetError(label1, "");
   label1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Your check is comparing the result of char.isDigit (which is a boolean) against the value of e.Handled (which is also a boolean). So your check is if this bool equals that bool instead of the digit check. Try: if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)){...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not checking `e.Handled` but set it to `true` when required

```
if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) {
  // Expected input, clear error messages
  label1.Text = "";
}
else {
  // Do not accept user input
  e.Handled = true;

  // Show error messages
  label1.Text = "Allow Only Numeric Values !";
}

// Let's not repeat ourselves
errorProvider1.SetError(label1, label1.Text);
```